# How to use nested variables in jinja2 templates

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How do I use nested variables of an item within the jinja templates? I am running ansible to produce configs for network switches.

Trying to get the if statement to be based on the bgp_peer_version,

I have the following variable files

```
 ---
 switches:
   - ansible_hostname: Core1
     bgp_neighbors:
       - bgp_peer_version: both
         bgp_peer_ipv4: 10.1.1.1
         bgp_peer_ipv6: 2001::1
         bgp_vrf:
       - bgp_peer_version: v4
         bgp_peer_ipv4: 10.1.1.2
         bgp_peer_ipv6: 
         bgp_vrf:

   - ansible_hostname: Core2
     bgp_neighbors:
       - bgp_peer_version: 'both'
         bgp_peer_ipv4: 10.1.1.2
         bgp_peer_ipv6: 2001::1
         bgp_vrf:
       - bgp_peer_version: 'v4'
         bgp_peer_ipv4: 10.1.1.2
         bgp_peer_ipv6:
         bgp_vrf:
```

and have the following code so far

```
{% if item[bgp_peer_version] == "v4" %}
BGP Peer
IPv4 address {{ bgp_peer_ipv4 }}
{% else %}
BGP Peer
IPv4 address {{ bgp_peer_ipv64 }}
IPv6 address {{ bgp_peer_ipv6 }}
{% endif %}
```

I am trying to build a template which uses the variables within the bgp neighbours for each of the switches. I am looking for an output with the first template.
Template 1 output

BGP Peer 
IPv4 address 10.1.1.1
IPv6 address 2001::1
BGP Peer 
IPv4 address 10.1.1.1

Template 2 output

BGP Peer 
IPv4 address 10.1.1.2
IPv6 address 2001::2
BGP Peer 
IPv4 address 10.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"How do I use nested variables (of an item) within the jinja templates?"*

A: Is this probably what you're looking for?

```
{% for item1 in switches %}
{% for item in item1 %}
{% if item[bgp_peer_version] == "v4" %}
result is V4
{% else %}
result if both
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Edit the question, make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), add expected result, format it properly and delete this comment.